# How do themes impact the visual design of a WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress-theming, web-development-server, visual-web-developer

I want a complete and detailed solution about theme impaction on visual design of a wordpress website

I Tried to find solution but cant be able to get reasonabe answer.I posted question here for complete and satisfied solution.